# Why the following error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I am building a nested resource like

```
 resources :blogs do
    resources :comments
  end
```

when I visit the following

blogs/1/comments/2, I received the error

```
undefined method `comment_url' for #<#<Class:0x4173108>:0x43b45d8>
```

Here is the code inside views\comments_comment.json.jbuilder

```
json.url comment_url(comment, format: :json)
```

How to fix?

Edit per suggestion

```
json.url blog_comments_url(comment.blog, comment, format: :json)
```

However the URl I get is always like
"url":"http://localhost:3000/blogs/1/comments.json"

I would like to get something like
"url":"http://localhost:3000/blogs/1/comments/2.json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `rake routes`, you should see something like this:

```
    blog_comments GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index                                     
                  POST   /blogs/:blog_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create                                    
 new_blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new                                       
edit_blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit                                      
     blog_comment GET    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show                                      
                  PATCH  /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update                                    
                  PUT    /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update                                    
                  DELETE /blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy                                   
            blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)                            blogs#index                                        
                  POST   /blogs(.:format)                            blogs#create                                       
         new_blog GET    /blogs/new(.:format)                        blogs#new                                          
        edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)                   blogs#edit                                         
             blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#show                                         
                  PATCH  /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#update                                       
                  PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#update                                       
                  DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)                        blogs#destroy
```

The first column has the path helper name without the `_url` or `_path` suffix.

Your `:comments` resources is nested within your `:blogs` resource so the helper names are also nested:

- `blog_comments` not `comments`
- `new_blog_comment` not `new_comment`
- ...

So the helper you're looking for is `blog_comment_url`. Also, since the resource is nested, the helper will want both the comment and blog as arguments:

```
json.url blog_comment_url(comment.blog, comment, format: :json)
```

Comment: I meet the error undefined local variable or method `blog' when using json.url blog_comment_url(blog, comment, format: :json)

Comment: Do I need to modify somewhere else like show.json.jbuilder? json.partial! "comments/comment", comment: @comment

Comment: I wasn't sure of the context so I had to guess. Maybe you can say `comment.blog` instead of just `blog`.

Comment: I think if using json.url blog_comment_url(blog, comment, format: :json), we need  to pass blog into, but don't know how.

Comment: Don't you have a `belongs_to :blog` in your comments? Your nested resources suggest that comments only exist as part of a blog.

Comment: I have belong_to in the model. Could you see my revised question?

Comment: I meant "instead of just `blog` in `blog_comment_url(blog, comment, format: :json)` use `comment.blog`" so `blog_comment_url(comment.blog, comment, format: :json)`.

Comment: I can use comment.blog, but the url is still not what I want. Please see revised question.

Comment: `blog_comment_url`, not `blog_comments_url`.